# How To Detect and Track Multiple Targets Simultaneously in vuforia's ios SDK?

Tags: ios, sdk, augmented-reality, vuforia

I want to detect two image targets simultaneously using vufoira. Can you help me?

I tried to write:

```
Vuforia::setHint(Vuforia::HINT_MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_IMAGE_TARGETS,2);
```

in initTracker function but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how to use Vuforia and Scene Kit. It detects 5 image targets simultaneously:

https://github.com/zihad2010/-Vuforia-SceneKit-simultaneous-object-detection-

I have tested it with vuforia-sdk-ios-6-2-9 and it works ok. But, not working with vuforia-sdk-ios-7-0-47.